# Possible to get latest NFT from a collection with web3.js?

Tags: web3js, nft

I want to show the most current NFT from a collection on a website.

Is this possible with web3.js?

I have a working example how to load all NFTs from a collection which are owned by a certain wallet account.

But I want to load only the most current NFT from a collection regardless which wallet account is the owner of the NFT.

Here is the working example I have:

```
import SpacePunksTokenABI from "./space_punks_token.js"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)

  document.getElementById("load_button").addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(SpacePunksTokenABI, "0x45DB714f24f5A313569c41683047f1d49e78Ba07")
    const walletAddress = document.getElementById("wallet_address").value
    contract.defaultAccount = walletAddress
    const spacePunksBalance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call()
    
    document.getElementById("nfts").innerHTML = ""

    for(let i = 0; i < spacePunksBalance; i++) {
      const tokenId = await contract.methods.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(walletAddress, i).call()

      let tokenMetadataURI = await contract.methods.tokenURI(tokenId).call()

      if (tokenMetadataURI.startsWith("ipfs://")) {
        tokenMetadataURI = `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${tokenMetadataURI.split("ipfs://")[1]}`
      }

      const tokenMetadata = await fetch(tokenMetadataURI).then((response) => response.json())

      const spacePunkTokenElement = document.getElementById("nft_template").content.cloneNode(true)
      spacePunkTokenElement.querySelector("h1").innerText = tokenMetadata["name"]
      spacePunkTokenElement.querySelector("a").href = `https://opensea.io/assets/0x45db714f24f5a313569c41683047f1d49e78ba07/${tokenId}`
      spacePunkTokenElement.querySelector("img").src = tokenMetadata["image"]
      spacePunkTokenElement.querySelector("img").alt = tokenMetadata["description"]

      document.getElementById("nfts").append(spacePunkTokenElement)
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to display all NFTs from a collection on a HTML page with OpenSea API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Show NFTs from collection</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+3&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        @keyframes gradient {

            0%,
            to {
                background-position: 0 50%
            }

            50% {
                background-position: 100% 50%
            }
        }

        * {
            color: white;
            font-family: "Source Sans 3", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.25rem;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-weight: 400;
            letter-spacing: .05rem;
            line-height: 1.5rem;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            /* Remove blue highlight of button on mobile */
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }

        body {
            background-color: gray;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #bg {
            animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
            background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
            background-position: top center;
            background-size: 200% 200%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #nfts {
            height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            top: 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        img {
            border: 5px dotted white;
            height: 50vw;
            width: 50vw;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xE29F8038d1A3445Ab22AD1373c65eC0a6E1161a4"; // BoredApeYachtClub -SEPOLIA
        let page = "";
        let nfts = null;
        getNfts();
        async function getNfts() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v2/chain/sepolia/contract/${CONTRACT_ADDRESS}/nfts?limit=10${page}`, {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'X-API-KEY': ''
                    }
                });
                const result = await response.json();
                console.log("Success:", result);
                nfts = result.nfts;
                // If there is a next page call getNfts() with page endpoint
                if (result.next) {
                    console.log(result.next);
                    page = "&next=" + result.next;
                    getNfts();
                }
                appendNfts();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            }
        }
        function appendNfts() {
            for (let index = 0; index < nfts.length; index++) {
                const nftElement = document.getElementById("nft_template").content.cloneNode(true);
                nftElement.querySelector("h1").innerText = "#" + nfts[index].identifier + " - " + nfts[index].name;
                nftElement.querySelector("a").href = `https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/sepolia/0xcf96edb0b569e2152118e01bc2458881c4807aa9/${nfts[index].identifier}`;
                nftElement.querySelector("img").src = nfts[index].image_url;
                nftElement.querySelector("img").alt = nfts[index].description;
                document.getElementById("nfts").append(nftElement);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <div id="nfts" class=""></div>
    <template id="nft_template">
        <section>
            <h1 class=""></h1><br>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <img class="" src="" alt="" onload="this.style.height='auto';this.style.border='none'" onerror="">
            </a>
        </section><br>
    </template>
</body>

</html>
```